# Testing profile Technical questions

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Where to find the technical question of different companies to prepare for written Test in Testing profile

Comment: Are you asking for a list of technical interview questions that companies commonly ask? If so, please update your question to say so, and tell us what you've done to try to answer your question.

Comment: Searching for my preparation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have prepared few Interview questions with answers Selenium and Java related question I had during my interview which are listed [here](http://qalititude.blogspot.in/2017/01/selenium-java-interview-question-i.html). I will be adding few more examples as well.

Also you will find lot of resources when you search google.